# Is there a way to make runtime bars more meaningful if there are a few cases of very long runtimes (due to missing dependencies)?

Tags: airflow

I am looking at this in the airflow GUI:

[image]

Generally, this task takes ~1min, but today it took ~9h due to continuously retrying for a missing dependency. As is this graph doesn't tell me much beyond that it was waiting for some dependency on today. Is there a reasonable way to make this graph more informative?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If your DAG is idempotent (as it probably should be), you could delete the DAG run so it runs again.